# shell script to set mysql timeout

Tags: shell, mysql

I have written a script to fetch mysqldump from a huge database. But the problem is it locks the table. So what i did is enhanced the script which will fetch the dumpfile in batches. ( I did it monthly basis) but still it locks the table. after googling and reading several blog posts I found that this problem of timeout. Now how do I set time out in shell script? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setup a replication slave, and when you want to dumping the data, use the slave instead of master
when mysqldump causing table locking, it does not affecting your current running application (which run on the master)

Comment: while dumping form slave are you sure that its not gonna lock as it does with the master?

Comment: that's the purpose of having slave, both server running on its own, while the slave only execute series of sql from master

Comment: but while running series of sql query its timing out.. and of course for slave too it will time out.. the problem is with fixing timeout not with master or slave. but anyway i will give a try with replication too if any luck.

Comment: replication is consider the better option for backup -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-solutions.html

Comment: hmm seems like i have to go for replication any how.. thanks :)

Comment: ok replication is my secondary choice.. i will surely look for that. now what i thought was dumping data in batches of small packets.. but now i got this error and I am a little confused. I began the query: 'mysqldump -C --options --where="true LIMIT 1270000, 500000"> dump3.sql' which begins from row 1270000 and upto 500000th records from there.. but the error is misleading. 
'mysqldump: Error 1317: Query execution was interrupted when dumping table `pageviews` at row: 2552' --> how does error occur at "2552th" row? or is the 2552th row comparative? anybody sure of it?

Comment: as i suggested replication is the better solution from all of your problems, and avoid extensive discussion in the comment -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_cant_reopen_table